# How do I insert/Delete from a cache data structure in O(1)?

Tags: data-structures

I have a key against which there will be a collection of items, And I have a global expiry configured from the user. And each item in the collection will have a Last used time.
I want to design an O(1) complexity solution for the above problem for three operations.

```
Add(); // Adds item

Get(); // Takes item

RemoveExpired(); // This will be triggered from a timer on the cache, 
//I need to call Remove on collections against each key which then will 
//remove its own expired items. With my current solution, I am able to achieve O(n*m).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a copy of the expiration time in a queue. And every time your timer expires you pop from the queue and delete all items that expired.

To use comparatively small extra space you could have the queue point to the same objects you're storing (which presumably have timestamps in them).

Comment: A Dictionary and Linked List Combination worked for me.

Comment: Basically the same thing.